# mongo lookup where array fields don't match

Tags: arrays, mongodb, lookup

I have two collections: **Users** and **Roles**.

Both use ObjectIds as their index.

Users has a field called *Roles* which holds an array of Role ObjectIds.

```
Users:
{
"_id" : ObjectId("590253b50985e614aaa90098"),
"roles" : [ 
    ObjectId("57d624612808daf641fafae3"), 
    ObjectId("5a2da7e37f1c84d172161273"), 
    ObjectId("5a2ede157f1c84d172161d33"), 
    ObjectId("5a2ede927f1c84d172161d34") 
}


Roles:
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57c6371cf541a6c9457f1319"),
"name" : "Admin"
}
```

I'm trying to identify the Role objectIds in the roles array of the User collection that DO NOT have a reference in the Roles Collection.

Any ideas? I've tried Aggregates, lookups, foreach, nin.. and have not found the right combination. Clearly I'm new to mongo :p

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `$lookup` is a form of "LEFT JOIN" so you always get the "master" items and then only the "joined" ones which match. If you want **Roles** which "don't match" **Users**, then do the `$lookup` from the **Roles** collection instead of the **Users** collection.` db.roles.aggregate([{ "$lookup": { "from": "users", .....` The ones which **don't match** will be those where the target array has "no items". Or just simply `$unwind` the target array, and get the distinct "roles".

Answer (score 3):

You must use $unwind, $lookup, $match and $group:

```
db.Users.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: "$roles"
},
{
    $lookup:
     {
       from: "Roles",
       localField: "roles",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "Role_info"
     }
},
{
     $match   : {
        "Role_info.0": {$exists:false}
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$roles"
    }
}]);
```